# Angular Filter Argument are always undefined

Tags: angularjs, filter, arguments, undefined

I have the following problem: I have a filter which filters a collection of clients base on 3 arguments (the status, the name, etc.). You can see it here:
"http://cholordoweb.com/"; you should download this page: "pantalla_gestion_usuarios.html" and this
"http://cholordoweb.com/recursos/panelUsuario.js" where the filter is defined...

The problem is that event If I select "Active" in my combo (which defines the client status), internally the corresponding argument is always undefined...

Do you know why is happening this ?.

Edited #1
The problem is simple: I have one filter with 3 arguments (2 combos and 1 textbox) and when I select an option and the filter mechanism is triggered, all the arguments are undefined... Can't reproduce it thats the other problem... I am lost...

Comment: please elaborate more & what error you are getting in console?

Comment: Try to reduce your problem so that it can be reproduced in a short [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/) or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I am not getting anything at the console... That's weird...

Comment: Another weird thing is that I access the angular scope through angular.element and the ng-model property related to the combo is always "undefined"...